Privacy Manifest for third party SDKs - iOS
I recently received a warning while uploading app to app store, to update the Privacy manifest for the third party SDKs I am using.
I am using Firebase in my application.
Questions:

Should I update my third party library with the added privacy manifest version.
I can directly include Privacy file into my app any update the reason manually without updating the third party SDKs to the latest version.

I would really appreciate if anyone could provide information or insights on this questions.

Any idea what if library dependency not added privacy manifest in their version? Do they need to do? or as library owner we can add on behalf of other dependency if not done?

If your Project is Running and Uploading Successfully. You can just add PrivacyManifestFile on the basis of usage Detail if it shows Error in building with Old Libraries You can update it.
